# How can I remove a certain type of values in a group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which is a small part of a bigger one:

```
   acc_num   trans_cdi
0     1         c
1     1         d
3     3         d
4     3         c
5     3         d
6     3         d
```

I'd like to delete all rows where the last items are "d". So my desired dataframe would look like this:

```
   acc_num   trans_cdi
0     1         c
3     3         d
4     3         c
```

So the point is, that a group shouldn't have "d" as the last item.

There is a code that deletes the last row in the groups where the last item is "d". But in this case, I have to run the code twice to delete all last "d"-s in group 3 for example.

```
clean_3 = clean_2[clean_2.groupby('account_num')['trans_cdi'].transform(lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] != "d") | (x.index != x.index[-1]))]
```

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't give the result you showed.

Comment: The problem is that it deletes all rows with "d".

Comment: Sorry I didn't read far along in your text. But there is still a problem that `clean_3` doesn''t look like your desired output. What do you want? Can you please update your question

Comment: @craze,  I would recommend Erfan's approach and accepting his solution, so I can delete my answer.

Comment: Actually, I have fixed the bug with the same approach I was trying to go with. It now seems like a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, compare to the next row with `shift` if the values are both equal to 'd'. `~` filters out the specified rows.
2. Second, Make sure the last row value is not `d`. If it is, then delete the row.

code:

```
df = df[~((df['trans_cdi'] == 'd') & (df.shift(1)['trans_cdi'] == 'd'))]
if df['trans_cdi'].iloc[-1] == 'd': df = df.iloc[0:-1]
df
```

input (I tested it on more input data to ensure there were no bugs):

```
    acc_num trans_cdi
0   1       c
1   1       d
3   3       d
4   3       c
5   3       d
6   3       d
7   1       d
8   1       d
9   3       c
10  3       c
11  3       d
12  3       d
```

output:

```
       acc_num  trans_cdi
0       1       c
1       1       d
4       3       c
5       3       d
9       3       c
10      3       c
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `idxmax` here with reversing the data `[::-1]` and then get the index:

```py
grps = df['trans_cdi'].ne('d').groupby(df['acc_num'], group_keys=False)
idx = grps.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x[::-1].idxmax()]).index
df.loc[idx]

   acc_num trans_cdi
0        1         c
3        3         d
4        3         c
```

---

**Testing on consecutive value**

```py
   acc_num trans_cdi
0        1         c
1        1         d <--- d between two c, so we need to keep
2        1         c
3        1         d <--- row to be dropped
4        3         d
5        3         c
6        3         d
7        3         d

grps = df['trans_cdi'].ne('d').groupby(df['acc_num'], group_keys=False)
idx = grps.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x[::-1].idxmax()]).index
df.loc[idx]

   acc_num trans_cdi
0        1         c
1        1         d
2        1         c
4        3         d
5        3         c
```

Still gives correct result.

Comment: This `x.loc[:x[::-1].idxmax()` is cool. I tried the same logic but without vectorization. +1

Comment: No problem man, happened to me many many times :) it's all about the learning @DavidErickson

Comment: Suggestion: We can change `df['trans_cdi'].ne('d').groupby(df['acc_num'])` to `df['trans_cdi'].ne('d').groupby(df['acc_num'], group_keys=False)` and `idx = grps.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x[::-1].idxmax()]).index`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this not so *pandorable* solution.

```
def r(x):
    c = 0
    for v in x['trans_cdi'].iloc[::-1]:
        if v == 'd':
            c = c+1
        else:
            break
    return x.iloc[:-c]

df.groupby('acc_num', group_keys=False).apply(r)

   acc_num trans_cdi
0        1         c
3        3         d
4        3         c
```